# Where and when does Franky say that Sanji is one of the strongest guys on the crew?

Tags: one-piece

I found this statement in the [Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Vinsmoke_Sanji/Personality_and_Relationships),

> Franky acknowledges that Sanji's strength is greater than his own, claiming that Sanji was one of "the strongest guys on the crew".

but I can't find where or when does that (Franky's claim) happens. The Wikia doesn't give any citation there.

Did Franky say that? If so, where and when did he say it?

Comment: FWIW, the statement was added on [12 Nov 2015 by an anonymous IP user](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Vinsmoke_Sanji/Personality_and_Relationships?diff=1304959&oldid=1304921) but without any sources.

Comment: Well, like Franky, most of the crewmembers regard Luffy - Zoro - Sanji as the monster trio and acknowledge that they are much stronger then the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Franky himself said this but it is widely accepted that Luffy, Zoro, and Sanji are known as the monster trio. They are the three strongest members of the Straw Hats. This would in itself imply that Sanji is stronger than Franky.

Answer (score 1):

In Enies Lobby, when Franky fights against Fukuro and Sanji against Jabura thanks to the upgrade of the diable Jamble